# How to sync database and angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngzone

I am trying to fetch data continuously from mongo database.

It needs refresh the page in order to get latest data.

My question, Is there any way to put angular service and component which will check & fetch data in real time?

Some of the way which i found in internet such as :

> Call the service in **setInterval** after few seconds.
>    or, Use of third party **fireloop**.

But really i don't want these strategy.

Could someone guide me how & where to proceed to achieve real time functionality ?

I am using anuglar v4 and mongodb v3.

Thanks.

Comment: use websockets https://socket.io/

Comment: true, useful link : https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1